# How to change the emmet "go to next edit point" setting in vim

Tags: vim, emmet

I'm using the excellent [emmet](https://emmet.io/) plugin in vim on Catalina (osx).
Does anyone know how to change the setting for "go to next edit point"?

Default values don't work and I don't know how to troubleshoot this? ‍♀️

Expansion of for example ul>li*5 works great and I was able to set

```
let g:user_emmet_expandabbr_key = '<c-e>'
```

that works.

I tried adding these three in my .vimrc but no effect:

```
 let g:user_emmet_next_edit_point = '<c-r>'
 let g:user_emmet_nexteditpoint = '<c-r>'
 let g:user_emmet_nextedit_point = '<c-r>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`:help emmet-customize-key-mappings`](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/blob/c7643e5b616430f766528b225528a5228adb43df/doc/emmet.txt#L1264) for a list of variables controlling emmet key mappings.

I believe the one you want is:

```
let g:user_emmet_next_key = '<C-r>'
```

The help entry also offers suggestions on using a `<plug>` mapping or using per-filetype mappings.

(Personally, I find the original [`<C-r>`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R) in Insert mode to be very useful, so I wouldn't use that particular key combination for a different purpose myself. YMMV.)

Comment: When I manually set 
let g:user_emmet_next_key = '<C-r>' then it works. Ctrl+R doesn't work for me when it's not in the .vimrc! Thank you so much for this! ✨

Comment: Also "Ctrl + R" is redo for me in vim, so I will figure out some other key combination. :]

Comment: @Alisso Isn't the next key mapped in Insert mode though? CTRL-R as "Redo" is in Normal mode... From your comments it wasn't clear to me whether there was something that still wasn't working for you (does it work when you override from your vimrc or not? your comment isn't very clear on that...) If you have a follow up question, let me know.

Comment: It works when I add it to my .vimrc, if I don't then it doesn't work.

So I put
let g:user_emmet_next_key = '<C-x>'
in my vimrc and trigger it witch Cmd+n using Keyboard Maestro.

Comment: If I just add  let g:user_emmet_next_key = '<C-r>' then redo doesn't work for me

Comment: I imagine it needs to be in your vimrc because emmet-vim will create the key-bindings when it's loaded, so the variable needs to be defined *before* the plug-in is loaded, which means it needs to be in your vimrc. For some reason I thought this was an Insert mode mapping, but from your experience it looks like it's a Normal mapping one... In any case, you can use what you find works best in your case!